# Dummy code box in LaTeX

Tags: code

I am not used to work in TeX and I need to write a dummy code box like in this style. I am not entirely sure how to replicate this style. I found some code boxes, but not in this structure that I want

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: There are different algorithm packages available, e.g. `alogrithm2e` or `algpseudocode` or ...